# Multicasting in ReactiveCocoa 3 and ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

Let's say I have a function that returns a `SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NSError>` and I want to bind the producer to multiple `MutableProperty<String>`. So, something like this:

```
let foo = SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NSError>(value: nil)
let someProperty1 = MutableProperty<String>("")
let someProperty2 = MutableProperty<String>("")

someProperty1 <~ foo
    .flatMapError { _ in
        SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NoError>.empty
    }
    .map { _ in
        return "test"
    }

// someProperty2 <~ foo etc...
```

In order to avoid my function (e.g. some network stuff) being run multiple times I would need to use multicasting. As far as I can tell from the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/swift2/CHANGELOG.md#using-startwithsignal-instead-of-multicasting), `startWithSignal` is the operator to use for this. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this in a declarative manner.

So, one approach could be to make the binding in the closure of the `startWithSignal`:

```
foo.startWithSignal { signal, disposable in
    someProperty1 <~ signal
        .map { _ in
            return "test"
        }

    // someProperty2 <~ signal etc...
}
```

However this will obviously fail because we need to get rid of the `NSError` part. Because we're giving a `Signal` (opposed to a `SignalProducer`), we cannot use `flatMapError` (in RAC4, `catch` in RAC3). And I do not see how `mapError` can do this for us? Lastly, I'm not even sure that this is the proper way to handle multicasting in RAC3/RAC4?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMapError` (and any other operators that must take a `SignalProducer` argument) before `starWithSignal`

```
let fooIgnoreError = foo
    .flatMapError { _ in
        SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NoError>.empty
    }


fooIgnoreError.startWithSignal { signal, disposable in
    someProperty1 <~ signal.map { _ in "test" }
    someProperty2 <~ signal.map { _ in "test2" }
}
```

If the `fooIgnoreError` is started only once, your underlying signal producer `foo` is guaranteed to be started only once too.

Answer (score 0):

I explained how to implement **multicasting** with an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946571/how-do-i-observe-a-signal-and-immediately-receive-a-next-event-if-it-has-alrea/34010425#34010425).

As for errors, you can make your property `AnyProperty<Result<Value, Error>>` to be able to forward errors. If you want the signal to terminate upon a failure, you can simply

```
signal.flatMapError { error in 
    fatalError("Error: \(error)") // or some other form of error handling, or simply ignoring the error?
    return .empty
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for. However, I'm not sure I understand how to multicast and be able to forward errors. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: I explained that a little bit more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34010499/401024.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, but I want the type to stay as  `SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NSError>`. The example from this answer maps it into `NoError` and the description from the link will include any errors in the `Next` value. Is it possible to achieve what I want?