# ReactiveCocoa 4: How to send error to an observer without interrupting the signal

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

```
let (signal, sink) = Signal<[CLBeacon], BeaconManagerError>.pipe()
```

When I call this because the user disabled the Bluetooth:

```
sendError(self.sink, error)
```

the `Signal` is interrupted and I don't receive more `next` nor `interrupted` events after enabling the Bluetooth back again. The `Signal` is broken.

How can I send `error` types to the `observer` without interrupting / breaking the `Signal`? I can't find in the RAC 4 documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By design, an error causes the signal to finish. The [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#failures-behave-like-exceptions-and-propagate-immediately) says:

> failures should only be used to represent “abnormal” termination. If
>   it is important to let operators (or consumers) finish their work, a
>   Next event describing the result might be more appropriate.

If you want to turn errors into `Next` events, you can use `flatMapError` operator as described [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#handling-failures) or use `retry` if you want to allow only several occurances of the error.

Comment: Both of your links are returning 404 now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different semantics than `Next* (Error|Completed)` I recommend encoding that in the type. You can use a `Signal` that can't fail, **but which values can be either success or failure**, by using `Result`:

```
Signal<Result<[CLBeacon], BeaconManagerError>, NoError>
```

That `signal` will emit no errors, but its `Next` events will be `Result.Success<[CLBeacon]>` or `Result.Failure<BeaconManagerError>`, **and the signal won't terminate when receiving a `Result.Failure`.